# Unable to locate package ros-groovy-executive-smach-tutorials

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed groovy on Ubuntu-12.10 Quantal following standard ROS instructions.

I could install executive_smach stack but when I try to install executive_smach_tutorials doing... .
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-executive-smach-tutorials
...I receive this error:
Unable to locate package ros-groovy-executive-smach-tutorials

What it works:
roscd smach
roscd smach_ros

What it doesn't
roscd smach_tutorials

Please if you could help me on how to include the repository where smach_tutorials is inside ROS tree I would really appreciate.

(I have tried using rosinstall including URI of code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/executive_smach_tutorials on /opt/ros/groovy/.rosinstall
etc... It doesn't work :( )

Thank you very much in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61515/unable-to-locate-package-ros-groovy-executive-smach-tutorials/) by [ingestado](https://answers.ros.org/users/4754/ingestado/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The smach tutorials stack can be found here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/executive_smach_tutorials/trunk?rev=40356

I'll migrate it to github soon.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2